# invalid conversion from 'int (*) (int)' to 'int'

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why do i get this warning on `return somatorio;` on the line 24?

> invalid conversion from 'int (*) (int)' to 'int'

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int somatorio(int soma){
    soma+=soma;
    return soma;
}

int fatorial (int n){
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return (n * fatorial (n-1));
}
        
int combinacao(int num){
    int k = 1;
    while(k<=num){
    int combinacao = (fatorial(num)) / ((fatorial(k)) * (fatorial(num - k)));
    somatorio (combinacao);
    k++;
    }
    return somatorio;  // <-- Warning here
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    cout<<combinacao(num)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add filler text to the question to bypass the system requirements. The requirements are there for a reason; in this case, add the text of the warning you're getting.

Comment: Just change the signature of `int combinacao(int num)` to `auto combinacao(int num) -> int(*)(int)` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: `somatorio` is a function, not a number. Because you wrote `int combinacao`, it's supposed to return a number, not a function.

Comment: In that function `int combinacao(int num)` you have `somatorio (combinacao);` that calculates a value then throws the result away. I am not sure if you wanted to sum all of these results or what.

Comment: how do I store the result in a variable?

Comment: For example in `int combinacao = (fatorial(num)) / ((fatorial(k)) * (fatorial(num - k)));`, you store the result of `(fatorial(num)) / ((fatorial(k)) * (fatorial(num - k)))` in an integer variable called `combinacao`.

Comment: If you want to sum these. Create a sum variable on the line before or after `int k = 1;` initialize that variable to 0. Then in your loop `sum += somatorio (combinacao);` and finally at the end `return sum;` instead of `return somatorio;`

Comment: This is an exercise for school/university to practice recursion, right? Otherwise, you could just calculate two to the power of n.

Comment: @Xaver yes it is

Comment: I suggest you remove the function `int somatorio(int soma)` entirely (because it doesn't do what you want it to do) and sum the values up in the function `int combinacao(int num)`.

Comment: `int somatorio(int soma)` returns double the value of the passed parameter so in this case it returns `2 * combinacao` each time you call it.

Comment: @Xaver the exercise requires to have her

Comment: It's not possible the way you are doing it. `somatorio` has to have two arguments: The old sum and the summand you want to add to this old sum.

Comment: @Xaver how do i do this?

Answer (score 6):

In `int combinacao(int num)`, you have `return somatorio;`.

Based on the function signature, you have to return an integer. But `somatorio` is a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int` (`int (*)(int)`), it is not itself an `int`.

Am I correct in assuming that you want to calculate the sum of binomial coefficients? In this case, I can tell you that the method you provided for summing up the coefficients will not work as expected. In fact, you only multiply each value by two and never save the result.

If you want to sum the values up, you have to define a variable to store the sum, add the coefficients to this variable, and then return the value stored in this variable.

Comment: what would be the solution?

Comment: @VictoriaMoraes That depends on what you expect the code to do, which you haven't really explained.

Comment: I need the sum of the combinations

Comment: @VictoriaMoraes There are lots of strange things in the code. I expect the warning is not the only thing that is wrong with your code. But until you say what it is supposed to do it's hard for anyone to make any suggestions.

Comment: Just edited my answer. I hope it is clearer now what you have to do.